# How do I privately tell the mods that I think a user is using a bot-net to gain points?

Tags: support

How do I privately tell the mods that I think a user is using a bot-net to gain points? Is there a way to do this privately?

Comment: flag any of the answer and explain

Comment: Flag one of the users posts using the "Other" flag explaining your reasoning

Answer (score 6):

Flag one of the posts by the user (question or answer, doesn't matter).

Use the "Other" flag reason and explain. Be as thorough as you can be.

---

Alternatively, use the "Contact Us" link at the footer to contact the Community Team about such a user, with a link to the profile page of said user.

Answer (score 3):

Pick the "Other" flag type. You can flag any of his questions or answers and write down all the things there are about these.